# UICollectionView registerClass not working in UIViewController (with pics, code, & log)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a program that I want to split the screen into two different sections (UISplitViewController is not applicable here because I already have a UINavigationController as the rootMenuController.

The problem is that I can't get my UITableView or my UICollectionView to use the `registerClass` method. For UITableView it's not a problem, but it's required for the UICollectionView. I ran the simulator to show what it looks like with the UICollectionView disconnected.

What am I doing wrong where it won't register the class for cell reuse identifier>

```
#import "SELMenuViewController.h"

@interface SELMenuViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *backButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *paymentButton;

@end

@implementation SELMenuViewController
- (IBAction)employeeSelect:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}

- (IBAction)paymentScreen:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"payment screen");
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:    (NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"menuCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"text";
    return cell;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.itemsOrdered = [[UITableView alloc] init];
        self.menuItems = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame     collectionViewLayout:[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init]];
    [self.menuItems registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"menuCell"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Here is the error log...

2014-07-29 18:52:40.302 OlymPOS[2267:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UICollectionView.m:3241
2014-07-29 18:52:40.306 OlymPOS[2267:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier menuCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001019a5495 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010170499e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001019a531a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001012a0f19 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 189
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010083e2b7 -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:] + 1324
    5   OlymPOS                             0x0000000100013efe -[SELMenuViewController collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] + 110
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000100831cae -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 264
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010083330b -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 3581
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000100836ae1 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 243
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000100311993 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 354
    10  QuartzCore                          0x0000000104475802 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 151
    11  QuartzCore                          0x000000010446a369 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 363
    12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010446a1ea _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    13  QuartzCore                          0x00000001043ddfb8 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 252
    14  QuartzCore                          0x00000001043df030 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 394
    15  QuartzCore                          0x00000001043df69d _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101970dc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101970d37 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101950522 __CFRunLoopRun + 946
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010194fd83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000104002f04 GSEventRunModal + 161
    21  UIKit                               0x00000001002b1e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    22  OlymPOS                             0x000000010000f663 main + 115
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001025235fd start + 1
    24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

[image: iOS Simulator]
[image: Xib image]

Comment: You are trying to register the default `UICollectionTableViewCell`. I think you're forced to subclass it before trying to use it like that

Comment: It looks like you made the table view and collection view in the xib file, so why are you creating new ones in initWithNibName?

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks! That was definitely what my problem was. I didn't have them referenced as IBOutlets and I was trying to allocate new ones. I fixed that and put my ``registerClass`` methods in the ``viewDidLoad`` method and voila!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a collection view in init, register your class properly, and set it to your (presumably) outlet.

Then, the view will be loaded, which happens *later* than init, and this will create *another* collection view and assign it to the outlet. This collection view hasn't had a class registered, so it fails.

It's not clear why you are bothering making a collection view if there is one in your xib, unless it was a desperate workaround.

The right thing to do is register the class in `viewDidLoad`, by which point the collection view from the nib will exist.